# Отключение Яндекс советника

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть задача отключить Яндекс советник, решил этот вопрос своим скриптом, ссылка https://github.com/ozzbabym/kick_sovetnik , если есть решения лучше, подскажите(работает OZON, Wildberries)

```
function kickSovetnik () {
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll('body > div[id]');
    var styles = document.querySelectorAll('style');


    Object.keys(elems).forEach(function(item) {
        if (/[a-z0-9]{11,13}$/.test(elems[item].id)) {
            elems[item].remove();
        }
    });

    Object.keys(styles).forEach(function(item) {
        if (styles[item].style && styles[item].innerHTML.includes('38px !important;')) {
            styles[item].remove();
        }
    });

    document.querySelector('html').style.marginTop = '0';
};

observer = new MutationObserver( kickSovetnik );
var  options = {
    'childList': true
};
var body = document.querySelector( 'body' );

observer.observe( body , options );
```

Comment: Ознакомитесь, пожалуйста, со страницей [на какие темы здесь можно задавать вопросы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), ваш вопрос не соответствует ни одной из тем. (у вас рабочий вариант кода, тут же помогают с не рабочим)

Comment: Перенеси из вопроса ответ в ответы.

Comment: @ΝNL993, ну теоретически можно [tag:инспекция-кода] притянуть за уши, но вопрос вроде не об этом.

Answer (score 0):

Изменения:

- Заменил `Object.keys`, на `Object.values`, потому что вы значение ключа используете только для того чтобы достать значение. И естественно переписал обращения к значениям
- Переписал ф-ии в `forEach` как стрелочные, просто так :)
- Объявил все переменные как `const`, просто так надёжнее
- Писать в селекторе `body div[id]` бесполезно и так все `div`-ы находятся только в `body`, потому убрал его
- Заменил `document.querySelector('html')` на более короткую запись `document.documentElement`. Обязательно прочтите [заметку](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/documentElement#notes), не всегда можно так заменять
- Заменил `document.querySelector('body')` на более короткую запись `document.body`
- Заменил `ykickSovetnik` на `kickSovetnik`, т.к. в исходнике у вас так написано

Код:

```
function kickSovetnik() {
  const elems = document.querySelectorAll('div[id]');
  const styles = document.querySelectorAll('style');

  Object.values(elems).forEach((item) => {
    if (/[a-z0-9]{11,13}$/.test(item.id)) {
      item.remove();
    }
  });

  Object.values(styles).forEach((item) => {
    if (item.style && item.innerHTML.includes('38px !important;')) {
      item.remove();
    }
  });

  document.documentElement.style.marginTop = '0';
};

const observer = new MutationObserver(kickSovetnik);
const options = {
    'childList': true
};
const body = document.body;

observer.observe(body , options);
```